# Compare max of two data in subarray python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, numpy

I wanted to compare each data in my two arrays
Ex:

```
array1 = [[0.4 0.6], [0.2, 0.8]...]
array2 = [[0.9 0.1],[0.7, 0.3]...]
```

in this case it should be

```
result = [[1, 0], [0, 1]]...
```

Get the class based on the element index.

Comment: Deleted tags `machine-learning`, `scikit-learn`, `svm` as they not related to the question.

Comment: For example, from your question it's unclear why it is the output that should result from the input. Can elaborate more on what exactly is your goal and provide a testable example (including dummy data)?

Answer (score 1):

You can use a for loop like this ...

```
result = []

for i in range(0, len(array1)):
  # loop through each element in the first array (each index (i) will be a subarray)
  for j in range(0, len(array1[i])):
    subarray = []
    # loop through each element within each sub array
    if array1[i][j] > array2[i][j]:
      subarray.append(1)
    else:
      subarray.append(2)
  
  result.append(subarray) # this will append the array to the array result
```

Also, this code assumes that both arrays have the same amount of elements so you might want to embed it in a try, except block.

I'm sure there are a few other ways you could do this too, a recursive solution will probably work.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to base the class in the index of the max, assuming that when the two subarrays share the max at different indexes,  the class is `[1,1]` you could try this:

```
array1 = [[0.4,0.9], [0.2, 0.8],[0.4,0.6]]
array2 = [[0.9,0.1],[0.7, 0.3],[0.9,0.1]]
res=[[1,1] if (max(x+y) in x)&(max(x+y) in y) else([1,0] if (x+y).index(max(x+y))%2==0 else [0,1]) for x,y in zip(array1,array2)]
res
#[1, 1], [0, 1], [1, 0]]
```

Assuming that when the two subarrays share the max the value is `[1,1]` and based on the array with the max, you could try this, with a list comprehension and with `zip`:

```
array1 = [[0.4,0.6], [0.2, 0.8]]
array2 = [[0.9,0.1],[0.7, 0.3]]
result = [[1,1] if (max(x+y) in y)&(max(x+y) in x) else([1,0] if max(x+y) in y else [0,1]) for x,y in zip(array1,array2)]
result
#[[1, 0], [0, 1]]
```